# Страницы PHP

Tags: php

подскажите каким способом можно сделать, когда к примеру на главной минимум выводиться новостей из БД, снизу делаю 1,2,3,4 страницы в зависимости от новостей сколько их и т.д Подскажите как это сделать? сейчас делаю новости...

Comment: Такая штука называется пагинатором. В интернете много статей и я думаю не стоит в очередной раз расписывать принцип. Дерзайте!)

Comment: для пагинации есть функции и много плагинов в популярных cms, например в wordpress.

Comment: скачай видеокурс Е.Попова "php + mysql для начинающих" - кроме всего там есть урок как делать постраничную навигацию

Comment: Евгений, перелогиньтесь.

Comment: Я уже скоро соберу специальную секретную команду, которая под видом Попова будет выпускать нормальные курсы. Дай бог, ситуация изменится.

Comment: видеокурсы ? вы обречены. есть только один стоящий видеокурс, но он по erlang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем вот вам формула :

R - количество записей всего(например в базе)

E - сколько записей нужно поместить на страницу

S - остаток от деления

P - количество страниц

R = 93

E = 10

R % E = S(3)

(R - S) / E = P(9)

если S больше нуля, то P + 1

В итоге у нас 10 страниц, в цикле формируем список страниц.

Как выбирать какую страницу показывать, описывать?